# Nvidia prime intel mode malfunction, Ubuntu GNOME 17.04, GTX 1050

Tags: gnome, 17.04, nvidia-prime

I have a Dell XPS 15 9560 (2017) with a GTX 1050 and I'm using Ubuntu with it. I've been trying to get hybrid graphics working lately to no avail. I have Nvidia proprietary drivers installed successfully but when I try to switch to Intel and log out, my screen will freeze when I try to log back in.

Some information:

- BIOS: 1.3.1
- Ubuntu: GNOME 17.04 - up to date
- nvidia drivers: 375
- kernel: 4.11.2-041102-generic

Do I need to install a specific Intel driver? I've seen others post about the same issue with success on KDE ([example](https://gist.github.com/marchelbling/14bf4157889e87eaecfd5834339e5163)), is this an issue with gnome?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is using an unsupported kernel.

Comment: I've used the regular old kernel for 17.04 and the result is the same. The example linked uses this kernel so I switched, but I can switch back to it if thats what it takes to fix it. And this is not a duplicate of that problem, I've installed both nvidia-375 and nvidia-prime.

Comment: After switching back to Intel have you checked to see if /etc/X11/xorg.conf has been moved to xorg.conf.xxxxxxxx file?

Comment: No, the xorg.conf file is the same before and after `prime-select intel`